# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Requiring the axios package with `const axios = require('axios');` is throwing an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` message.

I currently have Node version 12.16.3. Before that, I had version 14.2.0, and I was still getting the same message. Any help on how to fix this error message would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Chance are you're using it on browser / client side. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined